# thread1 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @shell:1:21

Tags: mongodb

I try to invoke username and email in mongodb 
that error appear

```
db.users.insert<<name:"abubakr",username:"bakr", email:"abubakr8911@gmail.com",password:"2016">>;
```

2017-09-18T17:32:54.606+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:21

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered a similar problem. I changed `db.users.insert(("username":"liaojianguo"));` into `db.users.insert({"username":"liaojianguo"});`
Then the problem was solved. You can try this method.